# How to place background with text over another background image without HTML

Tags: css, image, onhover

I made a form with checkbox as a forest image. I need to place another transparent background with text from html parameter (data-forest) over the forest checbox image but I have to do this only by CSS. I've tried so many solutions but no one work properly. Anyone have some idea?

Final effect **on hover**:

[image]

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ac9z8sgd/

**HTML**

```
<form action="action" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test" />
  <ul>
    <li><input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="forest_type" value="forest_1"><label for="checkbox_forest" data-forest="Estern forest">Forest 1</label></li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Default check button */
#checkbox + label {

  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Ds7gh7b.jpg?1');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
  padding: 15px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
/* Hover action */ 
#checkbox + label[data-forest]:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  content: attr(data-forest);
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Well, your selector is wrong... `label + label` indicates you are looking for the label that is a sibling of another label. Why aren't you using `#checkbox + label:hover`? If you can possibly create a jsfiddle with the issue, you'll more likely get a quicker answer.

Comment: Yes, it was older version. I updated code and paste jsfiddle link. Thanks!

Comment: Can you modify the HTML?

Comment: No :/ There is the problem. Only CSS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a pseudo-element.

```css
/* Default check button */

#checkbox + label {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/Ds7gh7b.jpg?1');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 275px;
  width: 184px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
/* Hover action */

#checkbox + label[data-forest]:hover::after {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  content: attr(data-forest);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<form action="action" method="get">
  <input type="hidden" name="test" value="test" />
  <ul>
    <li>
      <input id="checkbox" type="checkbox" name="forest_type" value="forest_1">
      <label for="checkbox_forest" data-forest="Estern forest">Forest 1</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[**JSfiddle with Transitions**](https://jsfiddle.net/ac9z8sgd/1/)

Comment: It looks very nice. Thank you! Maybye yoy have an idea to round 2 bootom corners of the transparent background ?

Comment: Sure, you can just put a border radius on the pseudo-element...but it may not look like you expect - https://jsfiddle.net/ac9z8sgd/3/

Comment: Yes, it's looks good because the original images are rounded. Hover action should show 1) background with text and 2) four rounded border around the image. I made the second effect but now 1 and 2 are biting each other. I recived small border around your text background - https://jsfiddle.net/ac9z8sgd/4/

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion:

```
label[data-forest]:hover:before {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  content: attr(data-forest);
  font-size: 20px;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 240px;
  margin-left: -15px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

BTW: Maybe 0.8 is too much a high value for a perceptible transparency. I'd make it 0.4.

Comment: Nice, I'll add few extra checkboxes (images) and I'll use general label selector. Thanks